# Use method from another class

Tags: android, methods

I have two Class. First is Main, the second is Ball,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    Ball tennisBall = new Ball (4,"green");
    tennisBall.bounce();
```

Now in the second Activity

```
 public class Ball extends Activity {
        private int size;
        private String color; 

 public Ball(int initSize, String initColor){ 
            size = initSize;
            color = initColor;
        }

 public void bounce(){

   //TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1); <???>
   //  tv1.setText("BALL");

        }
```

This textView i want to show in MainActivity
When I work with Log its working or in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making another activity object in you main activity that is wrong..

**solution:**

Pass the reference of the Textview to your ball class contructor and remove the extends activity..

```
 public class Ball {
        private int size;
        private String color; 
        private TextView tv;

 public Ball(int initSize, String initColor, TextView tv){ 
            size = initSize;
            color = initColor;
            this.tv = tv;
        }

 public void bounce(){


    tv.setText("BALL");

        }
```

Comment: @user2825342 sorry just remove the extend activity

Comment: @user2825342 no problems.. also mind if you click the up arrow as well thx

Comment: i cant becouse my reputation is stil low but i will, im just started whith this. thx again